# Change dates to first day of the month in R

Tags: r, date

How do I change my dates to the first day of the month...so 3/31/19 becomes 3/1/19, 2/28/19 becomes 2/1/19, and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Try `lubridate::floor_date`: e.g. `lubridate::floor_date(Sys.Date(), unit = "month")`

Comment: Please use the SO search function to search for identical posts to avoid posting duplicates.

Comment: @thelatemail Yup I realised, thanks. Added your dupe link. There are *a lot* of closely related questions, all of which would've been useful and relevant to OP.

Answer (score 1):

One of the many ways to do it is to use `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
date <- dmy('11/02/2019')
day(date) <- 1
date
```